# Tandem nursing infants of different ages

Tags: infant, breastfeeding

Does a newborn infant of 2 wk get enough nutrition from the breast milk which is also fed to a older child of one year in tandem nursing?
Our pediatrician said that the better quality milk made for newborn is unnecessarily taken up by the older child, which may cause the newborn to not get the sufficient  nutrition. But the local La leche representative did not object to tandem nursing and allowed it. So what are the evidence based guidelines , pros and cons of tandem nursing infants of different ages?

Also the older child is now  even more interested in breastfeeding then ever before on seeing her sibling feed , this inspite of the older child getting enough external foods. The older child feeds more frequently and for longer duration clearly showing  competing behavior.

Answer (score 3):

The [La Leche League](http://www.lalecheleague.org/nb/nbtandem.html) has a lot of info on tandem nursing.

Their [Tandem Nursing FAQ](http://www.lalecheleague.org/faq/tandem.html) states:

> Some mothers express concern that their toddler may be taking milk meant to nourish their baby. These mothers may take comfort in the fact that breasts are marvelous things that can adjust their production to meet the demands placed upon them--if they are asked to produce enough milk for two, they usually can! Also, most toddlers breastfeed considerably less frequently than an infant, and get most of their nutrition from other foods.

Edited to add:

Since I have not done tandem nursing, I can't speak to the specific pros and cons, but I don't think you should worry about your infants nutrition. In addition, while I couldn't find a good source, I believe you only produce colostrum for the first 2-3 days, and you mention the baby is 2 weeks already.

Comment: Does La Leche League offer any evidence for that assertion? Scientific studies?